# Wordpress media upload issue on AWS EFS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I have mounted AWS EFS on a directory created on root as staging. I checked with df -h it is showing as mounted. I then created a symlink as

ln -snf /staging /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/uploads

I made sure there was not upload folder before making a symlink.However when I try to upload media in wp-admin then I got the error as - **Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2018/08. Is its parent directory writable by the server?**

I am not sure why this error coming, though I have chmod all directories to 775 and files to 664, even ownership as apache:apache on all. Can someone guide me what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you show the output of the command ls - la /staging?

Comment: It is showing for all the directories
drwxrwsr-x. apache:apache

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. Actually the staging folder on which I had mounted my EFS should be writable by apache user. I chown that directory with `chown www-data:www-data staging` and the problem is solved.